# Laravel/Angular form value issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4

I have a form that i am populating via laravel / blade / php:

```
  {{ Form::text('itemid', $item['id'], array(...)) }}
```

This is ok but then when i add an angular model to it so i can then pass the form data through an `ng-click` event, the `ng-model` seems to take over and removes the set value form the form.

So the above will give me a text inout with say a value of 3.

Well as mentioned adding the below `ng-model`

```
  {{ Form::text('itemid', $item['id'], array('ng-model=>'item.name'...)) }}
  ....
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="itemData(item)">Confirm</button>
```

It removes the data set via php variable with nothing

Is there anything i am missing here?